# SQL Server function that returns RowVersion (the timestamp data type is invalid for return values)

Tags: sql-server

I have a database scalar function that returns the maximum `RowVersion` from a group of related tables (given some parent ID).

Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMaxRowVersion](@ParentId BIGINT)
RETURNS ROWVERSION
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
        (SELECT MAX(MaxRecordVersion)
         FROM
             (SELECT Id AS ParentId, RecordVersion AS MaxRecordVersion
              FROM dbo.TableA 
              UNION
              SELECT ParentId, MAX(RecordVersion) AS MaxRecordVersion
              FROM dbo.TableB 
              GROUP BY ParentId) X
         WHERE X.ParentId = @ParentId
         GROUP BY X.ParentId)
END
```

This does not work, and throws an error:

> The timestamp data type is invalid for return values

Is the only way to do this, to return a `VARCHAR` representation of it?

Comment: It looks like you should be able to return a timestamp data type, but that it has to be declared in your function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you please provide an example?  I have updated example code in the original question

Comment: Just read this in that article:  "return_data_type
Is the return value of a scalar user-defined function. For Transact-SQL functions, all data types, including CLR user-defined types, are allowed except the timestamp data type. " ?

Comment: Its not just timestamp but also  text, ntext, image and cursor cannot be the return types, a limitation for scalar functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) MS Doc:

> A nonnullable rowversion column is semantically equivalent to a binary(8) column. A nullable rowversion column is semantically equivalent to a varbinary(8) column.

Here is an example using a simple authors table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.returnRowVersion
(
   @id int
)
RETURNS BINARY(8)
AS
BEGIN
declare @ret BINARY(8)
set @ret=(select rowver from Authors where Id=@id)
return @ret

END
```